# Unmet Dependencies: mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-database-tools but it is not going to be installed

Tags: mongodb

Can anyone help me with this error?

**rohan@linux-pc:**~$ `sudo apt-get install mongodb-org-server` 
[sudo] password for rohan: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done**strong text**
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
mongodb-org : 
 **Depends:** mongodb-org-mongos but it is not going to be installed
mongodb-org-tools : 
**Depends:** mongodb-database-tools but it is not going to be installed 
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

**rohan@linux-pc:**~$ `sudo apt --fix-broken install` 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
mongodb-org : 
**Depends**: mongodb-org-server but it is not installed
**Depends:** mongodb-org-mongos but it is not installed
mongodb-org-tools : **Depends:** mongodb-database-tools but it is not installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies

**rohan@linux-pc:**~$ `sudo apt-get install mongodb-org-mongos`
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
mongodb-org : 
**Depends:** mongodb-org-server but it is not going to be installed
mongodb-org-tools : 
**Depends:** mongodb-database-tools but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

**rohan@linux-pc:~$**

Comment: Re-enable the disabled apt repo from which you obtained mongodb.

Comment: How to do that. Can you suggest? @MichaelHampton

Comment: Well, where did you get it?

Comment: I tried to install mongodb from https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/.
But I dont know how I get this eror...